# After successeded migration between cassandra database and vcloud director,cassandra data base did not appear any data

Tags: cassandra, vcloud-director-rest-api

When using `cassandra` query language to retrieve data from `cassandra` appears is there is no data and also did not appear any graph in vcloud director tenant portal, so i want to know how to solve this issue.

By the way a month ago i saw graphs in tenant portal.

[image: No graphs exist in vcloud tenant portals]

[image: Cassandra cql appears zero rows to retrieve]

Comment: So data in Cassandra doesn't just "disappear."  Unless of course, there is a TTL defined on the table in-question?  Otherwise, it's hard to know how to help you without more information.

Comment: TTL is 15 days to retrieve data